# Sharepoint / Office 365 limit External user to to see items in a list that they enter

Tags: permissions, external-users

I have a form that I want external users to enter data into. I would like to be able to:

1. Limit the External users to be able to enter and view just the items they add.
2. Limit the External users to NOT be able to Edit the items they add.
3. Limit the External users to NOT be able to download anything.

Form they fill in is created in InfoPath if that makes any difference (Good or bad)
And there is a look up link to another table, so The External users will have to have read access to that list as well

Answer (score 0):

I think External / Internal users would work the same.

1. You can go to List Settings and Set the list level permissions so
   the user can only edit the item they have created.

[image]

2. You will need to create a workflow to set the permission for the item to read only (impersonation workflow). More information [here](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/07/31/impersonation-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-workflow/) . Or move the item to another list based on the status/metadata.  More information [here](http://www.sharepointing.co.uk/2017/04/29/auto-move-sharepoint-list-items-using-flow/)